# Registration to mysql in json data type in .NET core

Tags: c#, mysql, json, asp.net-core

I am using MySQL and .NetCore. I have a table with Json data type. However, I am having trouble registering here via c #. I'm getting an error. How can I save Json data without destroying it?

DB Tablo

- Id => type Int
- Name => type nvarchar
- JsonData => Type Json

Json verilerini veritabanı üzerinden kaydediyorum. Json verileri, veritabanı üzerinden saklı yordamla kaydedilir. Ancak C # koduyla hata veriyor.

```
sqlconn = new MySqlConnection( ConnectionString );
      if (sqlconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
      {
        sqlconn.Open();
       }
      cmd = new MySqlCommand("call Ynkys.sp_JSON_INSERT(2, 22, 'Test', '"+jsonString+"')", sqlconn);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

ERROR=>:
Hide   Copy Code
{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Test', '{"Id":"22","Name":"AAAAAAAAAA"}')'' at line 1"}

How can I save Json type data in MySQL without destroying it?

My sp details

```
CREATE DEFINER=`developer`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_JSON_INSERT`(
    IN processType INT,
    IN Id INT,
    IN Name VARCHAR(45),
    IN JsonData  Json
)
BEGIN
    IF (processType=1) THEN 
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM Ynkys.JSON_ALL;
        END;
    ELSEIF (processType=2) THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Ynkys.JSON_ALL(Id,Name , JsonData)
             VALUES(Id,Name , JsonData);
        END;    
    END IF; 
END
```

Comment: Yeah so, imagine if your json data contained something like this. `MyField : "; Delete from orders;"`... there goes all your orders...  In short, you need to use parametrized queries

Comment: Please show us the definition of `sp_JSON_INSERT`

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`developer`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_JSON_INSERT`(
    IN processType INT,
    IN Id INT,
    IN Name VARCHAR(45),
    IN JsonData  Json
)
BEGIN
 IF (processType=1) THEN 
  BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM Ynkys.JSON_ALL;
  END;
 ELSEIF (processType=2) THEN
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Ynkys.JSON_ALL(Id,Name , JsonData)
    VALUES(Id,Name , JsonData);
  END;    
 END IF; 
END